# Web Services Explorer error 500 (again ??? 2024 ???)

Tags: eclipse, web-services, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jee

Impossible to launch the Web Service Explorer in Eclipse // Eclipse WTP / JSDK 1.7, 1.8, 21 // Win 11.

Each time I launch the Web Service Explorer it ends with:

*HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/el/util/JreCompat

URI: /wse/wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/el/util/JreCompat
SERVLET: org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet-f345f12
CAUSED BY: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/el/util/JreCompat
CAUSED BY: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/el/util/JreCompat
CAUSED BY: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.el.util.JreCompat cannot be found by org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp_9.0.52
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/el/util/JreCompat
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
.../...*

Please help.

Other info:
Windows 11 within Parallel Desktop on macOS Sonoma 14.1.2.

I tried with JSDK 1.7, 1.8, 17 & 21.

I reinstalled Eclipse 3 times, from both Java IDE version and WTP IDE.
I tried to solve the issue installing several plug-ins from Eclipse repository.
I added tomcat-util-9.0.0.M9.jar as external jar to the JREs.

... always the same result.

I want to use the Web Service Explorer to test the web services I am developing.

Thank you for your help.
Kind regards.

Comment: What Eclipse and WTP versions are you using? What are these several plug-ins you installed, and from what Eclipse repository? Why are you adding an outdated and *unfinished* tomcat-util milestone from nearly 8 years ago?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components) ||  Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) || Build id: 20231201-2043.

Plug-ins: Web Tools Platform (WTP) || software repository : https://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/latest

Why are you adding an outdated and unfinished tomcat-util milestone from nearly 8 years ago? --> I searched for a solution w/ google and found that this may solve the issue.

Comment: I'm ready to remove / reinstall Eclipse, JSDK and others.
So if you can tell me which version / from which repository I should take, I'll make a fresh new start.

Comment: I just did a fresh install on MacOS with "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components) | Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) |
Build id: 20231201-2043" that I downloaded from this URL :"https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2023-12/R/eclipse-jee-2023-12-R-macosx-cocoa-aarch64.dmg" that I found at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Same issue: HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/el/util/JreCompat
URI: /wse/wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
STATUS: 500

Comment: Please open an Issue at https://github.com/eclipse-webservices/webservices/issues .

Comment: Done --> https://github.com/eclipse-webservices/webservices/issues/2